# Need help in manufacturing my fictional metal to different shapes

Tags: materials, metals, metalworking

I'm trying to make a fictional metal, with the following characteristics:

- It doesn't have a melting point and heat won't affect the hardness or shape.
- It can absorb extreme heat but bad at cooling off and it will maintain or keep the extreme heat, but also not increase the heat, unless it surpasses its own previous heat limit, something like it's not stacking the heat.
- The metal is a strong conductor but has weak or almost no radiation or convection heat.
- It's also good for other chain reactions regarding absorbing or linking all forms of energy sources, such as mechanical, thermal, electrical, electromagnetic, and such, including impact.
- Just assume the metal has no impurity.
- It won't corrode or rust.
- The metal is the hardest and sharpest possible (technically typical indestructible metal) and not brittle so it has high tensile strength, maybe even infinite or no limits.

**Also, since the metal has no melting point and all those characteristics, I don't know how to shape it through blacksmithing or some other manufacturing method.**

**A modern blacksmithing method or a science fiction like method is acceptable but if a traditional or medieval way is possible, it would be appreciated.**

Some of the methods I have considered are through vacuum or outer space pressure, at least for extreme heat.  I really need metallurgy and blacksmith expert knowledge or solutions for this because I'm not knowledgeable of these things.

Also I was assuming something like hammers or machines made of that same metal can help shape it at least. Something like diamonds only can be cut by bigger diamonds.

*Also because of the metal characteristic that I have mentioned (the metal is bad at cooling off from extreme heat and a good conductor and other possible chain reactions) seems like it makes it unsuitable as armor, although would be appreciated if there's a way or solution to make it possible or reasonable, but not necessary though just curious of the possibility.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95297/discussion-on-question-by-li-jun-need-help-in-manufacturing-my-fiction-metal-to).

Answer (score 1):

Magic, a metal than cannot be formed by heating and is "the hardest possible" cannot be formed by *any* mechanical means heat assisted or otherwise and it cannot be ground using softer materials to ablate undesired sections. A material that's "the hardest possible" will have inter-atomic bonds of the same strength as the intra-atomic bonds of the [strong force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction) meaning that acids and other etchants, including [EDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_discharge_machining), will be ineffective as they won't be able to overcome the inter-atomic bonds. Thus the only option for forming this material is to invoke magic. That may mean [Clarke III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws) and it may mean a guy in dark robes and a pointy hat waving his arms that's up to you.

One possibility occurs to me; the fact that this material can't be worked *once formed* does not preclude it being formed in a usable shape *in the first place*.

Comment: It may be mined in highly impure form with lots of additives which messes up its structure and the refining, manufacturing process (incredibly complicated) cleanses these impurities out. It can use "scientific" buzzwords to make it believable. Not sure how current cutting edge nano materials made, but something along those lines. Also, some properties like the 2. are simply not possible. I would name it something like quantum heat folding, where the extra heat just go "pufff", disappearing from existence.

Comment: @Lupus I think a lot of nano materials use vacuum precipitation to lay down fine, at the molecular level, layers of material in a controlled fashion.

Comment: Thanks, will look it up myself sometime.

Comment: I was just thinking of [cold welding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_welding) as a partial solution to the problem of making it stick together when you're building it.

Comment: @Cadence If you could polish the material that would work I'm not sure about natural rough surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged this [science](/questions/tagged/science).

Are you aware of the [periodic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table) of elements? In the real world, it is possible to **sort** elements according to their atomic structure, and even to **predict** the characteristics of then [undiscovered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mendeleev%27s_predicted_elements) elements.

Today, the the undiscovered elements are very high on the table and generally radioactive. They are difficult to create and might usually decay in seconds or less. So an *undiscovered* metal with your properties is pure fantasy, or magic.

Your two chances are either an [alloy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alloy) or a [ceramic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceramic). 
Neither will be impossible to melt or re-shape, but a ceramic might come close enough for your purposes.

Comment: no im not knowledgeable about this hence my question, but eitherway its "fiction metal" as my first word there

Comment: @LiJun, some people make a distinction between "fiction", "science fiction", "science fantasy", and "fantasy". A fictional metal makes it hard to suspend disbelief, a fictional alloy or ceramic is easier to believe. Of course you can assign any properties you like to your fictional metal, but then it is pointless to ask here because there is no **scientific** answer.

Comment: there i remove it, are metalworking tag can accept my question?